# Arduino with sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, sensors

I am new to arduino and sensor. I am going to do a project related to E-nose to detect children breath odor. I wanted to use few sensors including 
Figaro TGS2602, TGS2600, TGS825, TGS2620 and TGS2180 together with arduino. May I ask is it possible for an Arduino Uno or Mega to support all these 5 sensors at one time?

Comment: No (Can't)! If your signal threshold values and your step value are not the same, you can't read them all from an analog input. Analog sensors show distorted values in frequency oscillations, which increases the cost of the power supply, so you can solve this event with an additional battery (i.e. AC-DC reducers are not healthy in analog circuits and require complete isolation).

Answer (score 1):

They are all analog sensors, so yes - you have 6 analog inputs on an Uno and 5 analog sensors, so you have one spare analog pin to do something else with if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!! By the way, is it logic if I use these 5 sensors for my breath odor detector project? Because from what I know some contents in breath might not match the sensitivity for these sensors. I have been told that research project might not necessary to have positive results. I just curious what result these 5 sensors bring if I use it.

Comment: All the datasheets for those devices have pretty graphs detailing the sensitivity. If that matches up with your requirements then they will work. If it doesn't then they won't.